# Building Swift, Objective-C and a Static C++ Library Together

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a static library from a third-party SDK — it's the FIT SDK that encodes and decodes "Flexible & Interoperable Data Transfer Protocol", used for various sports and fitness equipment. It's a binary format, well-described in the SDK, which also comes with a bunch of CPP, C-Sharp and Objective-C examples — plus a static library built from CPP source.

From what everyone seems to say, I should be able to build my Swift app with the static library, including the requisite bridging header.

I made a screenflow (https://vimeo.com/205082135) showing what happens, which is why I'm here.

I can get Xcode 8 (beta 3) to build a new, fresh project containing the library and even some Objective-C code. As soon as I add the bridging header, even with a rudimentary include, XCode craters with a Linker error, complaining that it can't find some class from the standard C++ library, like  or .
Smells like a configuration management issue with Xcode that I simply cannot sort out.

My sample project with the library is here: https://github.com/bleeckerj/Xcode-FIT-TEST

Has anyone seen this sort of thing before?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will completely solve your problem, but Swift can't interoperate with C++ directly. You'll need to wrap the C++ lib with an Objective C API and only expose that Objective C API to Swift.

Comment: Dave's comment is correct. You could use the C (not C++) API directly from Swift, or an Obj-C API if there is one (although based on the fact that your project has .mm files, I'm guessing there isn't a pre-existing wrapper). Otherwise you'll have to wrap it yourself.

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17

Comment: add a `.mm` (Objective-C++) file to your project, Xcode should then link your code with c++ std runtime

Comment: @BryanChen There are already several .mm files — they're actually Objective-C files that have been given a different extension to hopefully convince the compiler to build as if they were Objective-C++

Comment: With much more effort, I'm beginning to think that, in this particular case, because the static library was built with C++ and specifically using types that are incoherent to Swift (I'd love an explanation) such as <map>, <vector> and <string> (deduced from the README on this repository: https://github.com/sandym/swiftpp where it is explained that the tool makes accommodations for these parts of libstdc++ within Swift), I'm not at all sure that this combination of Objective-C, Objective-C++ and C can be built together. But — I would like to know for sure, so eager to hear any possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, through some help and lots of time and trials I managed to solve the problem and answer my own question.

Effectively one needs an Objective-C wrapper around the C++ (or Objective-C++) class containing the code one wants to expose and call from Swift. Then there's the Bridging Header that exposes just that Objective-C class. This particular Bridging Header is This sounds easy, and now it in fact *is* easy — but it was a mystery to me. It's a long-ish story, so I explain it as part of a sample repository https://github.com/bleeckerj/fit-sdk-with-swift derived from the FIT SDK that answers the question with an example.

Hope this is able to help anyone who comes across this problem.